# SSL handshake problem: server resets connection after "server hello done"

Tags: python, ssl, wireshark, handshake

So, I'm having a problem establishing a ssl handshake in python. After analyzing the captured packets in wireshark, I've detected that the server (in this example I'm trying to connect to https://www.google.com) just sends a FIN/ACK packet after the "Server Hello Done", not waiting for the client's response which comes after that, and then the connection ends with a hard RST from the server side.

Any ideas on why this could be happening? I've for example checked the cyphers sent in the "Client Hello" and "Server Hello" and they match correctly. What else could be going wrong in the handshake?

Additional notes: The original client request is a python request get with a field proxies, which is redirected and handled by a "super proxy". A connection is established between these two. Then, the "super proxy" sends the data received from the client, through a websocket, to a "proxyClient", which then sends the data to the server requested, and then collects the response, sending it to the "superProxy", which then sends it to the client. So this is the components involved in this handshake, which include several "redirections" of data between components.

Wireshark printscreen:

[wireshark_printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBzZe.png)

Comment: Do you control the server? Have access to logfiles on his side? Did you try with another client, like `openssl s_client`? You seem to have a convoluted setup, you need to reduce the variables. Try a direct connection to the server first, and see if that fails.

Comment: What I named "Client", "superProxy" and "proxyClient" are just python files that receive and redirect the requests. Also, the "server" I want to handshake with is defined by the client, in my example I'm trying to connect to "https://www.google.com/". This may look like a "convoluted setup" but it's the way required by my project. I was mainly looking for general problems that could happen in this type of handshakes. Also, I've had a simpler version of this project where I could establish a "direct connection", but the main goal is to handshake through these components.

Comment: If it works direct but not through your "proxies" (which are not really explained in your question, a proxy has a specific meaning in the network world), I think you can already point where the problem is. And without any code shown (which is kind of expected here to be ontopic) noone can troubleshoot things for you.

Comment: I know I didn't explained them well. But tbh I didn't think it was worth showing so much code and such, because it wasn't looking like a bug somewhere in the code. It looked to me like a handshake communication problem that could be obvious to someone by just looking at the wireshark packets. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You are saying "thinks work if i do A but do not if I do B", so I think the problem is in the difference between A and B. As for the packets you are not showing a lot of stuff, and not the TLS handshake details. The server drops the connection after the latest TLS record sent by client, so it means there is something in the record you send that the server does not like, and not very much in order to cut the connection so abruptly. Redo your test, case 1 that works record the TLS records sent by your client, case 2 that does not, record the TLS records, and then compare both TLS records.